# Appending a concatenation of two strings to a list

Tags: python

Let us say , I have a list . And I have two strings , let's say , "abc" and "ced"  and I want to append concatenation of these two to a list  in python  , like "abcced" .

I had  the following code snippet :

```
     if t == 1 :
       j = n + " ifcnt " + str(ifcnt)
       lst_output.append(j)
    else :
       lst_output.append(n)

p = open("po.txt" , 'w')

for i in lst_output :
    p.write(i)
    print(i)
```

I had this saved in a file  "bool.py" .  In order to redirect the  output to a file , I ran the following :

python clarbool.py >> po.txt .

However ,  for lines where two strings are being appended , I am getting the output as follow :

if n = "an out is a single most interesting thing that we want "

```
"an out is  a single most interesting thing that we want " 
"ifcnt 5 "
```

The appended strings are getting added properly but a newline is coming in between apparently .

The output that I expect is   :

```
"an out is  a single most interesting thing that we want ifcnt 5 " .
```

What is the reason for a newline character being added in between  ? How to get the expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

The newline character is being added by the `print` function`s default argument for`end`.

call it like:

```
print("your string here", end="")
```

and it will do what you are looking for.

from documentation:

```
Docstring:
print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
```

Comment: But I think the problem is not about print . The problem is in appending , while appending the two strings the newline character has gotten added if I print out  the individual elements of the list  .

Answer (score 0):

In a addition to anuvrat's answer, do `print()` in the end of the code:

```
...
print()
```

Note: do `from __future__ import print_function` in the top line of the code if version of python is not 3

Also still best is:

```
...
p.write(''.join(list_output))
print(''.join(list_output))
```

Or:

```
...
p.write(''.join(list_output))
print(*list_output,sep='')
```

But still if version is not 3 have to do `from __future__ import print_function` in the top of the code

Answer (score 0):

```
p.write(lst_output[0] + lst_output[1])
```

Demo:

```
n = 'an out is a single most interesting thing that we want '
a = 'ifcnt 5'

l = [n, a]
print(l[0] + l[1])
```

> ```
> an out is a single most interesting thing that we want ifcnt 5
> ```